# How to achieve mutex on method in Kotlin and prioritize one thread before another?

Tags: kotlin, mutex, kotlin-coroutines

I have two kafka topics `my_priorized_topic` and `my_not_so_priorized_topic`. I want to have mutex on `EventProcessor.doLogic`, and always prioritize on handle messages from `my_prioritized_topic` before messages from `my_not_so_prioritized_topic`

Can anyone give me some pointers how to solve this with Kotlin, maybe with coroutines?

```
class EventProcessor {
  fun doLogic(message: String) {
    ... // code which cannot be parallelized
  }
}
```

```
class KafkaConsumers(private val eventProcessor: EventProcessor) {
  @KafkaConsumer(topic = "my_priorized_topic")
  fun consumeFromPriorizedTopic(message: String) {
    eventProcessor.doLogic(message)
  }

  @KafkaConsumer(topic = "my_not_so_priorized_topic")
  fun consumeFromNotSoPrioritizedTopic(message: String) {
    eventProcessor.doLogic(message)  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create two `Channel`s for your high and low priority tasks. Then to consume the events from the channels, use coroutines' [select](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/select-expression.html) expression and put the high priority task channel first.

Example (the String is the even):

```
fun process(value: String) {
    // do what you want with the event
}

suspend fun selectFromHighAndLow(highPriorityChannel: ReceiveChannel<String>, lowPriorityChannel: ReceiveChannel<String>): String =
        select<String> {
            highPriorityChannel.onReceive { value ->
                value
            }
            lowPriorityChannel.onReceive { value ->
                value
            }
        }


val highPriorityChannel = Channel<String>()
val lowPriorityChannel = Channel<String>()
while (true) {
    process(selectFromHighAndLow(highPriorityChannel, lowPriorityChannel))
}
```

To send stuff to those channels, you can use `channel.send(event)`.